Merge cells in a pandas dataframe
I have the below dataframe in pandas:



Company Name
Product
App Name
August-2024
September-2024
YTD Credits




Company A
Prod 1
App 1
12
13
25


Company A
Prod 1
App 2
22
25
47


Company B
Prod 2
App 3
10
10
20


Company C
Prod 3
App 4
9
1
10


Company C
Prod 1
App 1
4
10
14


Company C
Prod 4
App 5
3
9
12



I need to merge the rows in the above dataframe which have the same Company Name and I need to calculate the sum of YTD Credits for each Company and create a new column - Total Credits. The resultant table would look like below:

desired result
I can calculate the Total Credits using:
df['Total Credits'] = df.groupby('Company Name')['YTD Credits'].transform('sum')

I can merge the cell in the Company Name using:
company_wise_df = pd.DataFrame(df).set_index(['Company Name', 'Product'])

The final table looks as below:

current table
However, I am unable to merge the cells in the Total Credits column.

Pandas doesn't support merging cells, you can do this when exporting to excel though
